# c++ to c#'s "As"?

Tags: c++

How do I cast a struct to one of its base types?

In c# you can do that with the keyword "as" like `Entity as Monster`. How can I do this in c++?

This is my structure:

```
struct Entity
{
    USHORT X;
    USHORT Y;
    UINT Serial;
    USHORT SpriteID;
};

struct Monster : Entity
{
    UINT UNKNOWN;
    BYTE Direction;
    USHORT Type;
};

struct Item : Entity
{
    BYTE UNKNOWN1;
    USHORT UNKNWON2;
};

struct NPC : Entity
{
    UINT UNKNOWN1;
    BYTE Direction;
    BYTE UNKNOWN2;
    BYTE NameLength;;   
    byte Name[];
};
```

Comment: A note: in the C and C++ worlds, `ALL_UPPER` is usually used with macro/constant definitions. `UpperFirst` or `lower_all` is usually used for type names (such as structs and classes) and `lowerFirst` or `lower_all` is used for variable names. It would be easier for others to understand if you follow one of these conventions (the one you like better). And even more importantly, don't mix conventions, for example `UNKNOWN1` and `Direction` both as members of a struct.

Comment: Usual question, why do you want to do this? Whatever behaviour you are doing with the data should live on the struct. Put a virtual function on the base class and override it on derived class, e.g. `updateTime`, `makeNoise`, `display`, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++, this possibility exists only for pointers to objects of *polymorphic* types (i.e. types with at least one virtual function). You can do it with a [`dynamic_cast<PtrType>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_cast).

Here is a complete example ([also on ideone](http://ideone.com/U823Sd)):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {virtual void foo(){}};
struct B {virtual void foo(){}};

int main() {
    A *a = new A();     
    B *b = new B();
    A *aPtr1 = dynamic_cast<A*>(b);
    cout << (aPtr1 == 0) << endl; // Prints 1
    A *aPtr2 = dynamic_cast<A*>(a);
    cout << (aPtr2 == 0) << endl; // Prints 0
    delete a;
    delete b;
    return 0;
}
```

The first `dynamic_cast` fails, because `b` points to an object of a type incompatible with `A*`; the second `dynamic_cast` succeeds.

Comment: does the virtual function need to actually do anything?

Comment: @Dean No, it simply needs to be there. The reason for it is that the compiler needs to store the run time type information (RTTI) somewhere, and keep a pointer to it in the object itself. The vtable (the place where compilers store pointers to virtual functions) is an excellent place to store RTTI, because the object already has a pointer to vtable. However, the compiler may not create a vtable for classes that have no virtual functions, and would therefore have no place to store RTTI.

Comment: @Dean Note that this is almost never an issue, because if you are building a type hierarchy with inheritance, you're nearly certainly want to have a virtual destructor.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, shouldn't the compiler itself then create a virtual table (or any extra space) to store RTTI even if it doesn't exist?

Comment: @Shahbaz The compiler may not decide to add a vtable upon discovering that you need RTTI, because doing so will change the class layout. This would be very bad in situations when you have a separately compiled module that does not use RTTI: the objects from these two modules would be incompatible, even though they'd be of the same class. Besides, that would be against C++ philosophy of no magic: the language puts you in tight control over every aspect of the binary code that it generates for you; it would be simply wrong for the compiler to slip a new pointer into your class behind your back.

Comment: In hindsight we should have added another way to make a class polymorphicc, e.g. `class Foo { virtual; };`. But for now just make the dtor virtual. That's always present and generally not called virtually.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at C++ type casting operator:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

```
Entity e;
Monster m = static_cast<Monster>(e);
```

If Entity had at least one virtual method you could do:

```
Monster * m = dynamic_cast<Monster*>(&e); // m != null if cast succeed
```

Note that C#'s "as" does not work on `struct`.  In this case you would have to cast the object in C# which is equivalent to a `static_cast` in C++.

Your program will simply not compile if the conversion is not valid.

Comment: In fact Sylvain Defresne is right it only work if the class has at least one virtual method.